# How to check if a server is running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ping

I want to use ping to check to see if a server is up. How would I do the following:

```
ping $URL
if [$? -eq 0]; then
    echo "server live"
else
    echo "server down"
fi
```

How would I accomplish the above? Also, how would I make it such that it returns 0 upon the first ping response, or returns an error if the first ten pings fail? Or, would there be a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do above?

Comment: add spaces around your `[` and `]` or just code `if ping $URL ; then`

Comment: (Of course, you cannot ping a URL, just a server.)

Comment: What are the cases which are neither a success nor a failure?  Perhaps you want to think harder about your criteria.

Comment: @tripleee It would only ever be a success or failure. Success = server responds, failure = server doesn't respond (after n attempts)

Comment: You may get a response to one out of the ten pings byt lose the rest, indicating network problems. I interpreted your question as not defining how to handle this scenario, but now upon rereading, I suppose you would call this a success. That's fine if it's really what you want, but I would use a single ping and want an alert if it fails.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the clarification, how would you do a single ping?

Comment: On many platforms, `ping -c 1`.

Answer (score 15):

I'ld recommend not to use only `ping`. It can check if a server is online in general but you can not check a specific service on that server.

Better use these alternatives:

#### curl

[man curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

You can use `curl` and check the `http_response` for a webservice like this

```
check=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -L "${HOST}${PORT}/" -o /dev/null)
if [[ $check == 200 || $check == 403 ]]
then
    # Service is online
    echo "Service is online"
    exit 0
else
    # Service is offline or not working correctly
    echo "Service is offline or not working correctly"
    exit 1
fi
```

where

- `HOST` = [ip or dns-name of your host]
- (optional )`PORT` = [optional a port; don't forget to start with `:`]
- `200` is the normal success http_response
- `403` is a redirect e.g. maybe to a login page so also accetable and most probably means the service runs correctly
- `-s` Silent or quiet mode.
- `-L` Defines the Location
- `-w` In which format you want to display the response
  -> `%{http_code}\n` we only want the http_code
- `-o` the output file
  -> `/dev/null` redirect any output to /dev/null so it isn't written to stdout or the `check` variable. Usually you would get the complete html source code before the http_response so you have to silence this, too.

---

#### nc

[man nc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)

While `curl` to me seems the best option  for Webservices since it is really checking if the service's webpage works correctly,

`nc` can be used to rapidly check only if a specific port on the target is reachable (and assume this also applies to the service).

Advantage here is the settable timeout of e.g. 1 second while curl might take a bit longer to fail, and of course you can check also services which are not a webpage like port `22` for `SSH`.

```
nc -4 -d -z -w 1 ${HOST} ${PORT} &> /dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
    # Port is reached
    echo "Service is online!"
    exit 0
else
    # Port is unreachable
    echo "Service is offline!"
    exit 1
fi
```

where

- `HOST` = [ip or dns-name of your host]
- `PORT` = [**NOT optional** the port]
- `-4` force IPv4 (or `-6` for IPv6)
- `-d` Do not attempt to read from stdin
- `-z` Only listen, don't send data
- `-w` timeout
  If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout seconds, then the connection is silently closed. (In this case `nc` will exit 1 -> failure.)
- (optional) `-n` If you only use an IP: Do not do any DNS or service lookups on any specified addresses, hostnames or ports.
- `&> /dev/null` Don't print out any output of the command

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like this -

```
serverResponse=`wget --server-response --max-redirect=0 ${URL} 2>&1`

if [[ $serverResponse == *"Connection refused"* ]]
then
    echo "Unable to reach given URL"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: +1 in case the question really wants to know if it is reachable and serving

Comment: I +1 this answer, coz the ones that use ping will fail if there is a proxy involved (which is the case with me).

Answer (score 8):

Use the -c option with ping, it'll ping the URL only given number of times or until timeout

```
if ping -c 10 $URL; then
    echo "server live"
else
    echo "server down"
fi
```

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' ping works on windows as well, afaik

Comment: what i meant was , shall we keep this in a batch file ??

Comment: I think you need to run it in command prompt, I've no experience with windows, so can't answer you in a better way, sorry!

Comment: not running directly on windows , anyways , leave it

Answer (score 5):

Short form:

```
ping -c5 $SERVER || echo 'Server down'
```

Do you need it for some other script? Or are trying to hack some simple monitoring tool? In this case, you may want to take a look at Pingdom: https://www.pingdom.com/.

Answer (score 4):

I using the following script function to check servers are online or not. It's useful when you want to check multiple servers. The function hide the ping output, and  you can handle separately the server live or server down case.

```
#!/bin/bash

#retry count of ping request
RETRYCOUNT=1;

#pingServer: implement ping server functionality. 
#Param1: server hostname to ping
function pingServer {
  #echo Checking server: $1
  ping -c $RETRYCOUNT $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo $1 down
  else
    echo $1 live
  fi
}

#usage example, pinging some host
pingServer google.com
pingServer server1
```

Answer (score 2):

One good solution is to use MRTG (a simple graphing tool for *NIX) with ping-probe script. look it up on Google.

read [this](http://blog.webernetz.net/2014/01/09/mrtgrouters2-measuring-ping-times/) for start.

Sample Graph:

[image: Sample Graph]